# Open a a new tab instead of new window or same tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE in Firefox as plugin.

I have a link=find your password, instead of opening it into the same Firefox tab (or window), how would I open it into a new tab ?

Comment: I'd advise against this. in my experience Selenium IDE can't really handle working with multiple tabs, I'd stick with multiple windows instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path is to configure your browser to handle this and that should be one time configuration only.

1. Open a new instance of Firefox
2. Type `*about:preferences#general*` into url search bar and hit Enter
3. Under *Tabs* section check *Open new windows in a new tab instead* and
4. Finally, restart Fireox then try

Answer (score 0):

try to use selenium actions.

For open in new window:
Shift key down + click + shift key up

For open in new tab:
Ctrl key down + click + Ctrl key up